# how to implement rxjs subscription in angular 2?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a service with following code:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Observer} from 'rxjs/Observer';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';
import {Article} from './article';

@Injectable()
export class ArticleService {
public articleSelected$: Observable<Article>;
private _observer: Observer<Article>;

constructor() {
this.articleSelected$ = new Observable(observer =>
    this._observer = observer).share();
}
selectArticle(article:Article){
this._observer.next(article);
}}
```

and in my component:

```
export class seeArticle{

subscription: any;

constructor(private _articleService: ArticleService) {
}
ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this._articleService.articleSelected$
        .subscribe(article => this.onArticleSelected(article));
}
onArticleSelected(article){
    console.log("an article was selected",article);
}
}
```

When I select an article (by clicking on it) in another component, the selectArticle service function gets executed, no problem there.
However, `this._observer.next(article);` seems to trigger the following error:

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'next' of undefined"
```

Being very new to angular 2 and Rxjs, I cannot figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `this._observer` is not yet available when `selectArticle` method is invoked, because

```
observer => this._observer = observer
```

part is asynchronous.

So instead of creating Observable manually, use [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/EventEmitter-class.html) that wraps Observable properly for you:

```javascript
@Injectable()
export class ArticleService {
  public articleSelected$: EventEmitter<Article>;

  constructor() {
    this.articleSelected$ = new EventEmitter();
  }

  selectArticle(article:Article){
    this.articleSelected$.next(article);
  }

}
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/sz5Dzm1SoisTJlvj8RcQ?p=info

Comment: thx for your answer. Your plnk works, but for some reason on my implementation I got "Property 'next' does not exist on type 'Observable<Article>'" when I tried to switch to EventEmitter. Will study your plnk more closely and keep you posted...

Comment: I guess this is TS complains? Make sure it's `public articleSelected$: EventEmitter<Article>;` not `Observable` type. I updated demo.

Comment: yes, TS complains now. Ok, did that, no more complain, thank you. Still no "an article was selected" message in the log, though

Comment: I think you also need to provide `ArticleService` properly to components. Make sure you don't have `providers: [ArticleService]` in both of select and see-article components, because the instances of the services are not going to be shared. Ideally use `providers: [ArticleService]` on the common parent component or during bootstrap `bootstrap(App, [ ArticleService ])`. Check the demo again for this.

Comment: that was it, I removed the redundant 'providers: [ArticleService]' and it works! Thank you so much!